# Python - Html tables hyperlinking

Tags: python, html, hyperlink, html-table

I am new to Python scripting. I created an HTML page which is having 5 headings on the top, 5 Tables on the bottom of the page. If I click on heading-1, it has to goto table 1 and vice versa.

I am using `HTML.table()` function for creating tables and `HTML.link()` for creating hyperlink. But how to address particular location of the table I'm not able to find. Please suggest me better way, how to do this.

-- CODE --

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import openpyxl
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import HTML

def create_link(data,link, file_name):
    html_fil = open(file_name, "a")
    htmlcode_3 = HTML.link(data,link)
    html_fil.write(htmlcode_3)
    html_fil.close()

def del_html_file(html_file):
    if os.path.exists(html_file):
        os.remove(html_file)

# Main exe starts from here
html_data_1 = ["AAA"]
html_data_2 = ["BBB"]
html_data_3 = ["CCC"]
del_html_file("sample.html")
print('---EXECUTION Started---')

html_fil = open("sample.html", "a") 

create_link('TABLE1', 'sample.html#TABLE1','sample.html')
create_link('TABLE2', 'sample.html#TABLE2','sample.html')
create_link('TABLE3', 'sample.html#TABLE3','sample.html')
create_link('TABLE4', 'sample.html#TABLE4','sample.html')
create_link('TABLE5', 'sample.html#TABLE5','sample.html')

A = HTML.Table(header_row=['Table - A'])
A.rows.append([html_data_1, html_data_2,html_data_3])               

B = HTML.Table(header_row=['Table - B'])
B.rows.append([html_data_1, html_data_2,html_data_3])               

C = HTML.Table(header_row=['Table1 -C'])
C.rows.append([html_data_1, html_data_2,html_data_3])               

D = HTML.Table(header_row=['Table - D'])
D.rows.append([html_data_1, html_data_2,html_data_3])               

E = HTML.Table(header_row=['Table1 - E'])
E.rows.append([html_data_1, html_data_2,html_data_3])               

htmlcode_1 = str(A)
htmlcode_2 = str(B)
htmlcode_3 = str(C)
htmlcode_4 = str(D)
htmlcode_5 = str(E)

with open("sample.html", "a") as html_fil:
    html_fil.write(htmlcode_1)
    html_fil.write("<br />")
    html_fil.write(htmlcode_2)
    html_fil.write("<br />")
    html_fil.write(htmlcode_3)
    html_fil.write("<br />")
    html_fil.write(htmlcode_4)
    html_fil.write("<br />")
    html_fil.write(htmlcode_5)  
    html_fil.write("<br />")
print('---EXECUTION END---')
```

Comment: Wellcome to Stackoverflow community. Can you provide your code? For starting to work from there...

Comment: Is thee a module you are using with HTML.table()?  Show code you have